# Adding URL of a link pointing outside of a website next to the link text itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, manual

I'm reading *'JavaScript Missing Manual'* and there is this script that automatically adds URL of a link next to this link itself.

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.replace('http://', '');
    $['a'].after(' (' + href + ') ');
}); // end each
```

The problem is that it doesn't work at all. Could someone please explain me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$['a'].after(' (' + href + ') ');
```

to

```
$('a').after(' (' + href + ') ');
```

$ should be called as a function, not an array.

Although looking at your code, you probably want this instead:

```
$(this).after(' (' + href + ') ');
```

---

edit:

here is the full code:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
href = href.replace('http://', '');
$(this).after(' (' + href + ') ');
}); // end each
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did what you suggested, however it still doesn't work

Comment: I just tested it and it is working. Are you doing it after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: There you go, I completely forgot about the ready() function. Sorry, just started learning js and jquery. Thanks a lot for taking the time to get me reply.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a similar, but shorter, version?

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){
    $(this).after(" ("+$(this).attr('href').replace("http://",'')+")");
}); // end each
```

Pretty much fmsf's solution + a small modification to make the code a bit shorter. o/